# issue with "this" keyword in plugin and jQuery animate()

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, jquery-animate, this

I am trying my luck at authoring a plugin with jQuery but I am having a few issues.  So I want to make this plugin where I take some divs and add a ***read more*** or ***read less*** link after these divs.

When the read more link is clicked, I want to animate each div's height to the original height (*I say original because the div's height is shortened before the link is clicked*), and set the ***read more*** text link to ***read less*** - and then the other way around.  Similar to the slideToggle effect.

My issue seems to be the "**this**" keyword, animate() function, or perhaps it is a logic issue... not sure. Here is a link to a live example:  http://jsfiddle.net/f978v/

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because of the `if` condition inside `trunc` method where you check for `linkTxt` and decide to increase or reduce the height. Since you are using a local variable `linkTxt` to pass the text to `trunc` method it is always `read more...`. I have fixed in the below link, take a look

Working **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/f978v/1/)**

Comment: Oh! I see.. The linkTxt variable resets to its original value on every click, that makes sense.  I am still trying to make it so the *trunc* function works for all the divs and not just one - OOP stye.  Thanks for your help though... I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

In an effort to let others know about my implementation of this plugin, here is the complete code:  [truncate plugin code](http://istocode.com/shared/javascript/jquery/jmless/)